# Add list (from external sharePoint site) in web part

Tags: list, site, web

I'm using SharePoint 2007.
I need to web-part, in this web part I want to add list' this list is placed in external sharePoint site.

Comment: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/display-sharepoint-list-site-data-view-web-part/

Comment: Hi Monica Todd, is it possible to add list from external site without using SharePoint designer? I do not have an access to the designer.

Comment: Actually you can also use the Content Query webpart to query doc libraries or list  in other site  collections as well, if you know CAML it would be bonus as then you could design the result set to make it look friendlier.

Comment: There are readily available jQuery. Do some google and you will find a solution. (you can create custom web part). (Create a solution to consume list using web services).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe BDC Meta Man http://lightningtools.com/products/bdc-meta-man/ can be an easy solution to your case.